# Xbox One Controller Compatibility

Tags: drivers

I'm a very new, basic Linux user and was trying to get my Xbox One controller to work with my pc and Elementary OS setup. I want to specifically use it for game emulation (RetroArch). I can't seem to get the device to communicate with my pc using Elementary. I try both plugging into usb port, and bluetooth and neither seem to work. I've tried downloading xdrv through the terminal but it doesn't seem to want to download. I think I may be missing the requisite drivers for this to happen, but maybe it's something else? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same trouble.
You don't note what kind of OS you use (Freya, Loki or something else). But you have to know there is no support for the xbox-one gamepad in ubuntu-based OS with kernel earlier than 4.5.
I have install kernel 4.8.5 (following [this](http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-8-on-ubuntu/) howto) and it's start working but only in Steam (Big Picture).
My question is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320377/xbox-one-controller-is-working-in-steam-but-is-not-working-in-games).
Please, try to get the kernel later than 4.5 and wright about the result.

Comment: Not sure what kernel Xubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) is using, but I got an Xbox One controller to work in it with this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam. It doesn't work in elementaryOS Loki though.

Comment: My problem is solved.. see the comment [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320377/xbox-one-controller-is-working-in-steam-but-is-not-working-in-games)